# Back button sets checkboxes to 'checked="checked"', but .checked to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found a very strange bug with our code where clicking out of a set of search results and then clicking back sets all the previously set checked filters to `checked="checked"`, but their actual `.checked` values to false. This causes a situation where the filter is effectively cleared out when the next page is clicked on, as it resubmits the form with page`++`'ed.

This is also causing some hiccups in our filter ordering:

```
$('.filters .sortable ul').each(function(idx, elem) {
    var ul_elem = $(elem);
    ul_elem.children().sort(function(a, b) {
      var inputA = $(a).find('input')[0];
      var inputB = $(b).find('input')[0];
      if (inputA.checked != inputB.checked) {
        return inputA.checked ? -1 : 1;
      }
...
```

In this case, inputA will return false for `checked` even though it was checked before (and has `checked=checked`). Is there a way to fix this without having an on-load script clean up the values?

Has anyone encountered a back button issue like this?

On latest Chrome, Yosemite.

Comment: are you asking why the back button takes you back to the last HTML, but doesn't change the javascript property you've set on an object?

Comment: It's not a javascript property though? -- `:checked` is an attribute that is getting morphed in to a `"checked"` attribute on back.

Comment: It's hard to follow your question, can you provide an HTML example?